# What does 'erotic in nature' mean?

Tags: meaning

> He turned the page of his book. ‘“Each wheel is divided into eight thick and thin spokes, dividing the day into eight equal pans. The rims are carved with designs of birds and animals, whereas the medallions in the spokes are carved with women in luxurious poses, largely ***erotic in nature***

I am wondering what the bold part could mean?

What is more, would you please throw some examples or vivid example to make it clear?

Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly has you wondering? Try googling "classic erotic art", click on images. If that's not vivid enough, I'd be happy to answer any question that you still may have...

Comment: The *nature of* the poses was erotic. The poses were *erotic in nature*. Which part do you not understand: *nature* or *erotic*?

Comment: If it's "nature" you stumbeled upon, see my comment here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51194/nature-of-the-data-nature-implication

Comment: 'erotic in nature'has connection with Some excitement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Erotic" means having to do with sex.

When we say that something is "X in nature" we mean that it is characterized by X. Like if I say, "This writing is technical in nature", I mean that an important characteristic of this writing is that it is technical. Often "in nature" is an unnecessary extra phrase. Like if I say, "This book is technical", versus "This book is technical in nature", the two sentences mean pretty much the same thing. The phrase does add some emphasis.

Sorry, I will not post "vivid examples" of women in erotic poses. You'll have to find those sort of pictures on your own.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. It was my specific answer. Thanks all.